# Is it safe to use serpentined power cord?

Tags: coil

We all know that the induction of a coiled up cord increases its impedance, resulting in greater heat proportional to the load.

We know not use coiled up power cords with heavy loads like heaters etc.

What about a serpentined power cord?  Does this configuration suffer the induction physics also?

Way long time ago, doing data center support, I overheard an electrician say to serpentine power cords instead of coiling them.  Have no idea of his source or knowledge level of the subject.

Answer (score 16):

The increased heating in a coiled cord has *absolutely nothing to do with inductance*. It's entirely because the heat generated has a harder time escaping, since it's all being generated in one place.

There are two things wrong with the inductance hypothesis:

- Inductance increases *impedance*, but it does not increase *resistance*. Only resistance generates heat in a cable.
- The current in the live and neutral wires is equal and in opposite directions, as long as there isn't a fault. Thus, the inductance cancels out, and winding has little impact on inductance--so the inductance of a coiled cord is not significantly different than that of a straight cord. (note the similarity to non-inductive windings for wirewound resistors.)

The advantage of a serpentine bundled cord is that it doesn't run the risk of getting badly torqued (which can cause reliability issues in the long term) when unbundled. If you don't rotate the end of a coiled cord while uncoiling it, the cord will end up with an overall torsion, and a tendency to spring back into loops and coils, which can be annoying in the short term and potentially damage the cord in the long term. A serpentine bundle does not have this risk.

However, because you still end up with a bunch of heat-generating cable bundled up in a small space, a serpentine bundled cable also causes increased heating. Whether it's more or less than a coiled cable is a complicated question, but it's definitely more than a straight cable with no bundling.